Action of $SL_2(F)$ on Heisenberg group and Weil representation
This a question arising from Bump's Automorphic Forms and Representations, Chapter 4.8, in the context of constructing the Weil representation.
Setup: Let $F$ be a field (in this context a local field, but I don't think this is really important for this question) and $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. Let $B$ a symmetric non-degenerate form on $V$ and $\psi:F\to\Bbb C$ a non-trivial additive character on $F$. The Heisenberg group $H$ is a group defined on the set $V\times V\times F$ with $B$ (I feel like writing out the addition formula in $H$ is not that important here, but for completeness I have included it below). In a similar way we define another group $A(V)$ on the underlying set $V\times V\times \mathbb T$ (using $\psi, B$; again I feel like the group structure is not essential to the question I am asking). There is a homomorphism $\tau:H\to A(V)$ given by $\tau(v^*,v,x)=(v^*,v,\psi(x)\psi(-B(v,v^*)))$. Now we define an action of $\operatorname{SL}_2(F)$ on $H$ by $$
g\cdot(v^*,v,x)=(av^*+bv,cv^*+dv, x)$$ where $g=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$.
Now on p. 532 Bump says that there is an evident action of $\operatorname{SL}_2(F)$ on $A(V)$ such that $\tau$ preserves this action. But it is not clear to me why that is the case. We have $$\tau(g\cdot(v^*,v,x)) = (av^*+bv,cv^*+dv, \psi(x)\psi(-B(av^*+bv, cv^*+dv)))$$
Now for the supposed action on $A(V)$ we this should be $g\cdot_?(v^*,v,\psi(x)\psi(-B(v,v^*)))$. I don't see how we can make this equal to the above by an action. It would need to be something like $$g\cdot_?(v^*,v,t) = \Big(av^*+bv,cv^*+dv,t\frac{\psi(-B(av^*+bv, cv^*+dv))}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))}\Big))$$
But this doesn't look like an action.
Things would seem to make a little sense if $B$ was antisymmetric instead, because then $B(av^*+bv, cv^*+dv)=B(v^*,v)$ (which also uses that we are working with $\operatorname{SL}_2$ and not $\operatorname{GL}_2$). But this is not compatible with the rest of the theory (where we need $B$ symmetric) and $\tau$ wouldn't be a homomorphism.
Group law on $H$: $(v_1^*,v_1,x_1)(v_2^*,v_2,x_2) = (v_1^*+v_2^*,v_1+v_2, x_1+x_2 + B(v_1^*,v_2)-B(v_1,v_2^*)).$
Group law on $A(V)$: $(v_1^*,v_1,t_1)(v_2^*,v_2,t_2) = (v_1^*+v_2^*,v_1+v_2, t_1t_2\psi(-2B(v_1,v_2^*)). $

This is too long for a comment, but may be it works as an answer. I believe that the formula
$$
g\cdot(v^*,v,t) = \left( av^*+bv,cv^*+dv,t\frac{\psi(-B(av^*+bv,cv^*+dv))}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))} \right)
$$
for $b=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$,
is actually an action. I'll provide my calculation for if you missed something that made you believe it is not an action, but I believe this is not necessary as you can verify it by yourself.
Let $g'=\begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \\ c' & d' \end{pmatrix}$, so that
$$
g'g=\begin{pmatrix}
a'a + b'c & a'b+b'd\\ c'a+d'c & c'b+d'd
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and thus
$$
(g'g)\cdot (v^*,v,t) = \left( (a'a+b'c)v^*+(a'b+b'd)v,(c'a+d'c)v^*+(c'b+d'd)v,t\frac{\psi(-B((a'a+b'c)v^*+(a'b+b'd)v,(c'a+d'c)v^*+(c'b+d'd)v)}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))} \right).
$$
On the other hand, write
$$
(u^*,u,s) := g\cdot (v^*,v,t) = \left( av^*+bv,cv^*+dv,t\frac{\psi(-B(av^*+bv,cv^*+dv))}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))} \right).
$$
Then
\begin{align}
g'\cdot (g\cdot (v^*,v,t)) &= g'\cdot (u^*,u,s)\\
&= \left( a'u^*+b'u,c'u^*+d'u,s\frac{\psi(-B(a'u^*+b'u,c'u^*+d'u))}{\psi(-B(u,u^*))} \right).
\end{align}
Now, note that
$$
a'u^*+b'u = a'(av^*+bv)+b'(cv^*+dv) = (a'a+b'c)v^* + (a'b+b'd)v,
$$
and
$$
c'u^*+d'u = c'(av^*+bv)+d'(cv^*+dv) = (c'a+d'c)v^* + (c'b+d'd)v,
$$
so that the first two components of $(g'g)\cdot(v^*,v,t)$ and $g'\cdot (g\cdot (v^*,v,t))$ are the same. Now, for the third component, we have
\begin{align*}
s\frac{\psi(-B(a'u^*+b'u,c'u^*+d'u))}{\psi(-B(u,u^*))} &= t\frac{\psi(-B(av^*+bv,cv^*+dv))}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))}\frac{\psi(-B((a'a+b'c)v^* + (a'b+b'd)v,(c'a+d'c)v^* + (c'b+d'd)v))}{\psi(-B(u,u^*))}\\
&= t\frac{\psi(-B(u^*,u))}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))}\frac{\psi(-B((a'a+b'c)v^* + (a'b+b'd)v,(c'a+d'c)v^* + (c'b+d'd)v))}{\psi(-B(u,u^*))}\\
&= t\frac{\psi(-B((a'a+b'c)v^* + (a'b+b'd)v,(c'a+d'c)v^* + (c'b+d'd)v))}{\psi(-B(v,v^*))},
\end{align*}
so that the third components are also equal and thus $(g'g)(v^*,v,t)=g'\cdot(g\cdot (v^*,v,t))$. It is clear that if $g=1$ is the identity matrix, then $1\cdot (v^*,v,t)=(v^*,v,t)$ so we indeed have an action.
I am a bit curious about what made you think this is not an action, so if you can tell me, I would really appreciate it!

Yeah, I think you are right. There were two reasons why I thought this wouldn't work: 1) I didn't write out the calculations completely, but for some reason I thought the $\psi(-B(v,v^*))$ in the denominator wouldn't cancel out correctly in the composition, but I think I just made an arithmetic mistake. 2) More importantly: The chapter is really about representations of $GL_2$, so why are we restricting to $SL_2$ here? I thought maybe there was something about this action that needed $det=1$ matrices, but this seems not to be the case with the action defined by this formula.

I think the $SL_2$ might be explained that when we want to show that a certain projective representation lifts to a genuine representation it might not work with $GL_2$
